# Amazon MWS : Access denied Error for ListOrders

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

Yesterday my code was working and today when I again check it is throwing an error. I want to fetch the orders from amazon India for which I have used Orders.ListOrders API of Amazon MWS here is my code :

```
$action = 'ListOrders';

        $params = array(
                    'AWSAccessKeyId' => $data['aws_access_key'],
                    'Action' => $action,
                    'SellerId' => $data['merchant_id'],
                    'SignatureMethod' => "HmacSHA256",
                    'SignatureVersion' => "2",
                    'Timestamp'=> gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time()),
                    'CreatedAfter'=> '2014-08-31T18:00:00Z',
                    'CreatedBefore'=> '2014-09-23T18:00:00Z',
                    'Version'=> "2013-09-01",
                    'MarketplaceId.Id.1' => $data['marketplace_id']
                );

        // Sort the URL parameters
        $url_parts = array();
        foreach(array_keys($params) as $key)
            $url_parts[] = $key . "=" . str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($params[$key]));

        sort($url_parts);

        // Construct the string to sign
        $url_string = implode("&", $url_parts);
        $string_to_sign = "GET\nmws.amazonservices.in\n/Orders/2013-09-01\n" . $url_string;

        // Sign the request
        $signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, $data['aws_secret_key'], TRUE);

        // Base64 encode the signature and make it URL safe
        $signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

        $url = "https://mws.amazonservices.in/Orders/2013-09-01" . '?' . $url_string . "&Signature=" . $signature;

        //echo $url;exit;

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        // Create DOM object and load eBay response
        $responseDoc = new DOMDocument();
        $responseDoc->loadXML($response);

        $response = simplexml_import_dom($responseDoc);

        //$parsed_xml = simplexml_load_string($response);

        //echo $url;exit;

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($response);
        echo '</pre>';
        exit;
```

Response :

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Error] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [Type] => Sender
            [Code] => AccessDenied
            [Message] => Access denied
        )

    [RequestID] => 890a9075-2993-4063-be60-922c43bb8428
)
```

1. What `[Message] => Access denied` error indicates ?
2. It was working yesterday and today it is showing error why ?
3. What should I do to make this work again ?
4. It is working on Amazon scratchpad

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put this curl option after `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);` and try again :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

Comment: Hi @hardik solanki, Added... but same error. I really got mad why this is happening

Comment: which data you have used ? are you running my code with the credentials I have provided to you yesterday ?

Comment: Yeah i have used that data

Comment: You have my email id right ? can you please send me that code which you are running. Let me look that code

Comment: yeah sure i'll send you an email.

Comment: yes  I have run that code and it is running perfectly let me find out what exactly causing an error

Comment: Ok My code is also right but I have interchange the merchant and marketplace id in parameters which is coming from the database. Because of Hardik I found this solution. Thanks bro you are my amazon MWS savior :P